# Determinant of a matrix subtraction/addition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm trying to find out for square matrices with $n \geq 2$ :
$$ \det(A-B) = \det(A)-\det(B).$$

I know that $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$, but I'm unable to find proof on why a subtraction (or addition) is not equal. Thanks.

Comment: What do you know about the size of the matrices? For $1\times1$ matrices, the equation does hold.

Comment: I've edited my original question and specified that they're square matrices with n >= 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $A = 5I, B = 3I$, where $I$ is an $n\times n$ identity matrix. In this case $\det A = 5^n, \det B = 3^n$ and $\det (A-B) = \det(2I) = 2^n.$ So, for example if $n=2$, $16 = 25 - 9 = \det A - \det B \neq \det(A-B) = 4$.

Comment: Ok right that makes sense. I guess the follow up would be to prove it if we consider that **_A_** and **_B_** were the same size. Or is that not necessary since it's a specific situation?

Comment: @user372852 These two matrices *are* the same size.

Comment: They must be the same size, otherwise $A-B$ does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is true if $A=B$.

In that case $\det(A-A) = 0$

and $\det(A) - \det(A) = 0$

so $\det(A-A) = \det(A) - \det(A)$